Multiprocessing manager can't pickle <class 'cv2.Mat'>
I made a multi-process program to analyze images from a camera. The first process constantly reads the image from the camera, the second analyzes this image, the third contains an HTTP server for returning the image. Frames are exchanged using multiprocessing.Manager.
import multiprocessing
import cv2

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
frame = manager.Value(cv2.typing.MatLike, None)

The following code initializes a ValueProxy to exchange a frame between processes. This code works fine on my PC. However, when deploying this program on another machine, the following error occurs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tablo/Apps/rvp-camera-service/src/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    camera_service = CameraService()
  File "/home/tablo/Apps/rvp-camera-service/src/camera_service.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.frame = self.manager.Value(cv2.typing.MatLike, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 723, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 608, in _create
    id, exposed = dispatch(conn, None, 'create', (typeid,)+args, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 89, in dispatch
    c.send((id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'cv2.Mat'>: it's not the same object as cv2.Mat


Both systems have opencv 4.9.0 and python 3.10.6. So far I don’t understand why the behavior is different

cv2.Mat should not exist in current opencv-python packages, or any packages of the past 10+ years. it's all numpy arrays. what did you do? [mre] required.

@Christoph Rackwitz. I have corrected. Now this is a minimally reproducible example. cv.Mat is wrapper for numpy array. Stores extra metadata information how to interpret and process of numpy array for underlying C++ code.

@ChristophRackwitz Here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e52540162fe40a341fc468b90049139b3523a87d/modules/core/misc/python/package/mat_wrapper/init.py#L4 I was rather puzzled too...

fascinating. the comment/docstring claims "extra metadata". looks like a single attribute, and IDK if that even does anything. oh well. "typing" probably explains a lot of it.

@ChristophRackwitz Relevant commit -- the documentation change is most useful there. Seems like a facility to allow providing inputs corresponding to higher-dimensional cv::Mats (ones you'd construct with this or similar constructors)..

What helped me was changing the first argument in the ValueProxy declaration (from cv2.typing.MatLike to cv2.Mat)
